# Execute marks without confirmation in mu4e

Tags: mu4e

In `mu4e` (email in Emacs with `mu`), the default behavior of `x` is to prompt for confirmation before executing marks, such as "delete" or "archive." I want to execute marks without confirmation.

Inspecting the function bound to `x`, I see:

```
(mu4e-mark-execute-all &optional NO-CONFIRMATION)
...
If NO-CONFIRMATION is non-nil, don’t ask user for confirmation.
```

So I run `M-:`, `(mu4e-mark-execute-all t)` and it works.

But defining the key in the mode map

```
(define-key mu4e-main-mode-map (kbd "x") (lambda() (interactive) (mu4e-mark-execute-all t)))
```

does not rebind the key.

How can I redefine the `x` key, or make no confirmation the default?

Comment: `(lambda() (mu4e-mark-execute-all t))` is not a command.  `(lambda() (interactive) (mu4e-mark-execute-all t))` is a command.  Only interactive functions are commands.  This question is undoubtedly a duplicate... perhaps someone can point one out?

Comment: Thanks @phils, that does work with the global key. I will edit the question to avoid the duplication and make it `mu4e` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different key map for the headers view. This works for me when viewing headers:

```
(define-key mu4e-headers-mode-map (kbd "x") (lambda() (interactive) (mu4e-mark-execute-all t)))
```

and this when viewing messages:

```
(define-key mu4e-view-mode-map (kbd "x") (lambda() (interactive) (mu4e-mark-execute-all t)))
```